# Lock screen wallpaper location

Tags: lock-screens, wallpaper

The Samsung Galaxy S4 comes with a TripAdvisor lock screen wallpaper that rotates images every X hours of places around the world. Every now and then, it has really cool ones that I would potentially like to save to use as my lock screen permanently, but I can't figure out where in the filesystem they are stored.

I have found a couple of posts saying it is located in `/data/data/com.android.settings/` or something like that, but my `/data` folder is empty.

TL;DR: Where does Android save the current lock screen image?

Comment: If your `/data` folder were empty, you'd have no apps installed, and just done a factory-reset from recovery but never booted the device afterwards :) Thing is: you cannot browse `/data` without having root privileges. So you'd need to root your device, and use a file browser supporting "root mode".

Answer (score 2):

That depends on your Android version, but only changes a little. Wherever it is, you need [root-access](/questions/tagged/root-access) to retrieve it.

**For Android 6 and under**:

```
/data/system/users/0/lock_wallpaper
```

While primary (mainscreen) wallpaper is available at `/data/system/users/0/wallpaper`.

**For Android 7+**, the file name has changed to `wallpaper_lock` and is still available at the same place. You may want to fetch `wallpaper_lock_orig` instead, however.

Answer (score 0):

On Lenovo S1La40 (Vibe S1 Lite, Android 5.1, rooted) under the folder `/data/system/users/0`, I found the following files:

```
root@S1La40:/data/system/users/0 # ls -la
-rw-rw---- system   system     253952 2017-05-16 20:06 accounts.db
-rw------- system   system      37448 2017-05-16 20:06 accounts.db-journal
-rw------- system   system        715 2017-05-16 20:05 appwidgets.xml
-rwx------ system   system     356866 2017-05-16 20:05 lock_wallpaper
-rw-rw---- system   system      56663 2017-05-16 20:19 package-restrictions.xml
-rwx------ system   system     209008 2017-05-16 20:06 wallpaper
-rw------- system   system         99 2017-05-16 20:06 wallpaper_info.xml
```

where `lock_wallpaper` is the lock screen wallpaper, a jpeg without an extension.

I have my new wallpaper under the name `majestic.jpg`, so I can do the following:

```
adb push majestic.jpg /storage/emulated/0/lock_wallpaper
adb shell
su
cp /storage/emulated/0/lock_wallpaper /data/system/users/0/lock_wallpaper
```

Answer (score 0):

My Samsung Galaxy Note 2 saved it under `/data/data/com.sec.android.gallery3d/files` as `lockscreen_wallpaper.jpg`

The uncropped file was in the same folder.

Answer (score -1):

It's in `/data/data/com.sec.android.app.themechooser/files`.

Answer (score -1):

In Samsung Galaxy S4 it's at the location `/data/data/com.sec.android.gallery3d/files/`.

Answer (score -1):

`Android\data\com.sec.android.wallpapercropper2\files`

This is where I found Lock Screen Wallpaper on Samsung Galaxy S6 Edge.

Answer (score -2):

Make sure you have USB debugging turned on and then it should be in the data folder under com.sec.android.**something**