# Location of wallpaper and lock screen images on Android 13

Tags: lock-screens, file-system, file-management, wallpaper

I have two different images that I use for my wallpaper and my lock screen. These images are of my two oldest sons and have been used for wallpaper and lock screen for a long time. I just had another kid and it is time to update these images to include all three of my boys. Problem is that I cannot find the images and am afraid that if I update the wallpaper and lock screen images, then the current images will be lost forever. I can't lose these images forever. Can anyone tell me how to locate them so that I can copy them to a safe location. I have seen a couple of posts for older versions of Android but it does not seem to apply to Android 13. The path provided in these posts dose not exist on my phone (or tablet).

Edit:
It was suggested that I include device info. Here it is.
Phone: Samsung Galaxy S20 FE
Tablet: Samsung Galaxy Tab S7+

Comment: I'd assume you have seen [Lock screen wallpaper location](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/59295/44325). As the answers hint, the device needs to be rooted for the user to see and access system files. It also may depend on the manufacturer since they can and do customize the Android OS, so mentioning the device model might also help.

Comment: Hi Andrew. Thank you for replying. What does "rooted" mean. I am just someone who uses these devices. I do not know much about how these devices actually work (i.e. low level stuff).

Comment: Rooted means that the device has been modified to provide access that is normally not granted by the manufacturer. If you just buy and use a phone it is not rooted. As a certain step in the rooting process erases all user data it is also not an option for you. So the only thing you can do is making screen shots of your launcher without app icons to preserver the visible part of your background image.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I know now what I must do.